# How to get all rules with specitic severity via SonarQube API?

Tags: csv, sonarqube

My company needs all rules we are using as a pdf or csv file. There are several other threads here on SO asking similar question **but most of them do not work, as the links are dead or anything else**.

I came across using the web API, but it simply does not work.

The REST GET I tried was this one:

```
/api/rules/search?language=java&severity=BLOCKER
```

and

```
/api/rules/search?language=java&priorities=BLOCKER
```

as there are inconsistencies in the documentation.

Most of the rules I get are `MAJOR` and some of them are `CRITICAL`, but not a single `BLOCKER`, which is the only severity I need.

So how can I only get the BLOCKER rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you are looking for is `severities`, not `severity`.

```
/api/rules/search?language=java&severities=BLOCKER
```

Working example:
https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/rules/search?language=java&severities=BLOCKER

[Link to the documentation](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/rules)

Comment: Too early to accept. I found the severity parameter on a page, but it told me severity instead of severities. Thank you!

Comment: @Manfred the official documentation you point at is an ancient one from SonarQube 4.3. The actual up-to-date [Web Service documentation|http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+Service+API] is now embedded into the server itself: see [this example](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/issues/search) which does document *severities*.

Comment: @Nicolas Well spotted, I've updated the answer with the right link: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/rules (rules, not issues)